# How to create arrays and assign value to any index in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

How can i achieve following javascript code in typescript.

```
var childs = [];
childs[34] = [12,23,54,65];
childs[122] = [43,56,23,31];
childs[212343] = [345,643,24,745];
console.log(childs);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is already a valid typescript code as typescript is a superset of javascript.

However, typescript lets you have types, so in this case you can do this:

```
var childs: number[][] = [];
childs[34] = [12,23,54,65];
childs[122] = [43,56,23,31];
childs[212343] = [345,643,24,745];
console.log(childs);
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20childs%3A%20number%5B%5D%5B%5D%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Achilds%5B34%5D%20%3D%20%5B12%2C23%2C54%2C65%5D%3B%0D%0Achilds%5B122%5D%20%3D%20%5B43%2C56%2C23%2C31%5D%3B%0D%0Achilds%5B212343%5D%20%3D%20%5B345%2C643%2C24%2C745%5D%3B%0D%0Aconsole.log(childs)%3B))

Notice that the only thing I added was the type of `childs` (`number[][]`), which can also be written like:

```
var childs: Array<number[]> = [];
// or
var childs: Array<Array<number>> = [];
```

You'll get a compiler error if you try to add anything else to the array:

```
childs.push(4); // error: Argument of type '4' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'
childs.push([2, "4"]); // error: Argument of type '(string | number)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'number[]'
```

Comment: sir compiler is giving an error "Duplicatie identifiers 'childs'" & "subsequent variable must have same type.variable childs must be of type number[][], but here has type '[number , number ,number]'" What should i do for this???

Comment: What is the code that results in those errors? (edit your question and add it there)

Comment: Thank u Sir , Code is now working . I havent initialized variables inside class constructor. I was initializing variables outside of constructor & was not using this keyword. Thank u